# PostgreSQL: Query to find number of free days?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3

I have table as given below. This table is showing that which vehicle will be **free/available** for users from **start date** to **end date**.

[image]

**Suppose**

There is vehicle id = 1 is available for user from 2018-01-15 to 2020-02-28 (in yyyy-mm-dd format). In this period any user can take a vehicle at rent.

**What i want:**

I want to calculate the no of free days in particular period.

Here period: Jan-2018 means (`1-Jan-2018` to `31-Jan-2018`).

**Calculation criteria for free days:**

For vehicle Id = 1 --> start date = `2018-01-15` and end Date =  `2020-02-28`

For Jan-2018 = 16 days 
(as total days in Jan is 31 but our start date is starting from `2018-01-15` for vehicle id =1)

For Feb-2018 = 28 days  (between `2018-01-15` to `2020-02-28`)

Comment: I don't understand your math, but off the top of my head, you will probably need to use a calendar table here to cover all the dates you want to report in your query.

Comment: I modified my answer for more clearification. @TimBiegeleisen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Select enddate, startdate, CASE 
      WHEN startdate<= '2017-01-01' and enddate>= '2017-01-31'  THEN ('2017-01-31'::date - '2017-01-01'::date)+1
      WHEN startdate<= '2017-01-01' and enddate< '2017-01-31' and enddate>= '2017-01-01' THEN (enddate::date - '2017-01-01') +1
      WHEN startdate> '2017-01-01' and enddate>= '2017-01-31' and startdate<= '2017-01-31'  THEN (('2017-01-31'::date - '2017-01-01'::date)+1) - EXTRACT(DAY FROM startdate::date))+1

      WHEN startdate> '2017-01-01' and enddate< '2017-01-31'  and startdate<= '2017-01-31'  and enddate>= '2017-01-01' THEN (enddate::date - startdate::date)+1
       end 
      as td  from table1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use minus operator and daterange data type for these two dates.

```
postgres=# select *,upper(intersection_range)-lower(intersection_range) as available_days from (select *, daterange(start_date,end_date) * daterange('2018-01-01','2018-01-31') as intersection_range from vehicle) a;
 vehicle_id | start_date |  end_date  |   intersection_range    | available_days 
------------+------------+------------+-------------------------+----------------
          1 | 2017-12-31 | 2020-02-28 | [2018-01-01,2018-01-31) |             30
          2 | 2017-11-30 | 2018-02-28 | [2018-01-01,2018-01-31) |             30
          3 | 2017-07-31 | 2019-02-28 | [2018-01-01,2018-01-31) |             30
(3 rows)
```

Best regards.

Comment: No its no my requirement please again read my question. if I want total available day for Jan-2018 then it will be 31 days and Jan-2018 must be lies between start date and end date.

Comment: When i am executing my query than this error is coming. 

ERROR: range lower bound must be less than or equal to range upper bound

Comment: @BREngineer second parameter of daterange function should be bigger or equal to first parameter. For example `daterange('2018-02-01','2018-01-01')` generates error (ERROR: range lower bound must be less than or equal to range upper bound). You should write it as `daterange('2018-01-01','2018-02-01')`